Visual Studio Code - Python variable explorer and console connected to script
I develop in Python and I come from Spyder, but want to look at VS Code as an option to work in. There are two things that I cannot seem to get set properly, even after reading multiple forums.
The first thing I try to have is the variable explorer block that Spyder has. I got something like this working in VS Code:

The issue with this is that I can only access it by right-click on the script and choose 'Run in Interactive Window' -> 'Run Current File in Interactive Window'. This does mean however that I have to work in the interactive file and changes to the script itself (on the left) are not put in the variable explorer. So when I change the script and run it again, the variable explorer will be empty again. How can I have the variable explorer updated when I run the script itself? (just like with Spyder).
The second thing is related to this: I want to use variables that are stated in the script in the console as well, but I cannot to get that to work either. So when I define variable "a" in the script, then I want to see its value when I enter it in the console. This does work in the interactive window on the right.

Try the debugging panel, and using ipython in the terminal.
